# How can I create unique random numbers in R?

Tags: r, function, random

I hope to generate random numbers between 1:100 and then test their divisibility by 3. I have created a loop.

```
v <- c(0)
for(i in 1:100){
  r <- floor(runif(1, min=1, max=100))
  if(r %% 3 == 0){
    v <- append(v,r)
  }
}
print(v)
```

However, the numbers do keep repeating as you can see in the following output. Is there any way to only generate unique multiples of 3 between 1:100. I am aware there's a way to use the seq function and generate the same numbers, but I still want to know how to acquire unique random numbers.

Output:

```
[1]  0 18 87 30 45 90 12 72 75 60 27 84 90 27 42 54 63 15 63 30 72 69 57 30  3  6 15 30  3
[30] 60 72  6  6 18 75 96 84 78 24
```

Comment: `i1 <- seq(1,100,by=1)` and `i1[i1 %% 3 == 0]` could help you!

Comment: Try `sample(100)`

Comment: sample(0:33)*3 will generate random numbers multiple of 3 between 0 and 100

Comment: @Duck Ahh yes, I'm aware of the seq function. But I'm still looking for a way to use unique random numbers since we're trying to explore different methods to do the same

Comment: @nike.96 : use your prefered search engine and look for "[r] random vector" -- e.g. duckduckgo.com. You find very good basic examples here -- no. 5 in results -- http://www.cookbook-r.com/Numbers/Generating_random_numbers/

Answer (score 0):

`sample(1:33)*3` is all the multiples of 3 in your range in a random order.